# Is it safe or reasonable to use the key parameter in a cryptographic hash function as a counter?

Tags: hash, keys

Not all the cryptographic hash functions have the counter parameter for making messages be different for each counter value. But many accept a key parameter.

Is reasonable to use the key parameter as a counter?

Is it safe?

Answer (score 1):

Hash functions don't have key as parameter. I assume you got that misconception from programming languages such as PHP where they allow you to set a key to turn them into HMAC, despite they're no longer plain hash anymore.

That counter is part of padding to make the message "Merkle-Damgaard-Compliant", and there are other ways to do that.